# breaking up large array into smaller arrays given a specific value

Tags: php, arrays

I am attempting to store virtualhost records in a database.  So I have a large array containing those records (from a conf file). I'd like to break this array up into smaller arrays each containing 1 virtualhost record.  Having some issues deciding the best way to do this.  The following is an example of the large array from a log with the numbers being array keys.

```
88=[<VirtualHost *:80>
]
89=[    ServerAdmin xxx@xxxx.com
]
90=[    DocumentRoot asdf/asdf/asdf
]
91=[    ServerName xxx.yyyy.com
]
92=[    ServerAlias xxx.zzzz.com    
]
93=[</VirtualHost>
```

Short version: break large array into smaller arrays at virtualHost /virtualHost

Thank You

Comment: What should the output look like?

Comment: Have you made any attempts on to do this yet?  Can you show your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I think the best way to do it would be to `implode` de array into a string and use the [DomDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php) or [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) classes.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's Array Slice feature is handy when splitting large arrays into smaller ones. Use this in combination with functions that get accurate offset and length values.

[PHP.NET Array Slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)